# MIT App Inventor TinyWebDB conflicting with Android Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, app-inventor

After a search on the intertubes I'm hoping someone here might have heard if there were any conflicts between Android's Jelly Bean and MIT's App Inventor.

I've built a quiz that runs from a database. I have a web app to manage the quiz and then I used the App Inventor to create user interfaces to the quiz. They work by querying the database through a PHP using TinyWebDB.

Now all is fine and good when I'm only using one device. And then all is fine and good when I use multiple devices that aren't running Jelly Bean.

However when I do try to mix the operating systems, what happens is that all other devices stop and just the Jelly Bean works with the script. I have absolutely no idea how this could possibly happen, but when you are playing along happily and a jelly bean device joins the quiz every other instance stops querying.

Seems odd. I haven't yet tested the app with multiple Jelly Bean devices running, as I'm not rich enough to own more than one at the moment.

So if anyone has heard anything or can point me to even a hint of an idea of a solution it will do a lot to wards stopping me ramming my head into the wall.

Thanks.

Comment: [see my recommendation here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/GXMfpX7MgHs/cVPLlzuALaYJ) and, btw this is the same recommendation as to your [other quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18375323/1545993). If I were you, I would get rid of the TinyWebDB component and use the web component instead for the communication with your php script...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This turned out to be an unknown issue with the Web Host provider. Despite more than a dozen detailed requests for what on their side was blocking things I was always referred to how my own equipment or own code was at fault.

Set myself up a VPS and presto change-o I have a working system with no modifications to the code or the equipment.

TIL I don't like people who cover up their incompetency by blaming others.

Comment: great, you found the problem, we need more competent persons like you to answer TinyWebDB questions...